# How get the user id if the user isn't connected to your app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbml, fbconnect, xfbml

Is it possible to get the user id if the user isn't connected to your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the users login name (i.e. email) you can do a query like this:

> https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=USER_LOGIN&type=user&access_token=ANY_ACCESS_TOKEN

You can use any valid access token to run this request.

The resulting Data object contains user name and user id.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook doesn't allow you that without permission!

https://graph.facebook.com/me